# Wrapping text in table-latex

Tags: tables, two-column, wrap

[i am trying to insert a table into a two column document. but i was unable to do it. i have tried many things but not able to get the correct way. I want the table to be in center of the page even the document is two column oriented

```
\lipsum[1] 

\begin{table*}
    \centering


    \begin{tabular}[b]{l l l l l l l l}

    &   2011 &  2012 &  2013 &  2014 &  2015 &  2016 &  2017        \\ \hline
Networking &    0.15 &  0.23 &  0.42 &  0.65 &  0.85 &  1.01 &  1.15        \\
NoSQL &     0.07 &  0.13 &  0.29 &  0.5 &   0.8 &   1 &     1.2     \\
Infrastructure Software  &  0.14 &  0.44 &  0.83 &  1.08 &  1.25 &  1.6 &   1.9     \\
SQL &   0.62 &  0.88 &  1.31 &  1.75 &  2.25 &  2.45 &  2.7     \\
Cloud  &    0.36 &  0.62 &  1.19 &  1.82 &  2.52 &  3.05 &  3.65        \\
Storage &   1.1 &   1.75 &  3.09 &  4.2 &   5.5 &   6.4 &   6.95        \\
Computation &   1.53 &  2.29 &  3.65 &  4.92 &  6.4 &   7.1 &   7.6     \\
Apps \& Analytics       &   0.52 &  0.99 &  1.69 &  3.45 &  5.29 &  6.65 &  7.75        \\
Professional Services         &     2.8 &   4.42 &  6.15 &  10.1 &  13.5 &  16 &    17.2        \\


    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This is the caption for complicated table}
    \label{tab:1}
\end{table*}

 \lipsum[1]
```

Comment: Did you try with `\begin{table*}` ... `\end{table*}`? This is just a guess because you didn't explain the kind of document, and how you format the table. Could you do it?

Comment: The `table*` environment should do the job.

Comment: i tried table* , but its appearing in the new page, if I use [H] the table is getting disappeared

Comment: `table*` can only go to the top of the page. Placing it in the middle of the page would only make unclear to the reader how the text is split across the four chunks.

Comment: since `table*` can go only at the top of the page, that means it must be input *before* the page on which it should appear, although that means its position in the input is not "logical".  adding comments in appropriate places in the input to explain what has been done is very useful in such a situation.  also, since it might be necessary to move the table code around in the input, you might consider putting it in a separate file and calling it in; that's a lot more reliable than moving big chunks of code around in a file, even with a good editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cuted` package (from  the `sttools` bundle) and its `strip` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum, array, booktabs, caption}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{strip}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[b]{l l l l l l l l}
    & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014 & 2015 & 2016 & 2017 \\ %
    \midrule
    Networking & 0.15 & 0.23 & 0.42 & 0.65 & 0.85 & 1.01 & 1.15 \\
    NoSQL & 0.07 & 0.13 & 0.29 & 0.5 & 0.8 & 1 & 1.2 \\
    Infrastructure Software & 0.14 & 0.44 & 0.83 & 1.08 & 1.25 & 1.6 & 1.9 \\
    SQL & 0.62 & 0.88 & 1.31 & 1.75 & 2.25 & 2.45 & 2.7 \\
    Cloud & 0.36 & 0.62 & 1.19 & 1.82 & 2.52 & 3.05 & 3.65 \\
    Storage & 1.1 & 1.75 & 3.09 & 4.2 & 5.5 & 6.4 & 6.95 \\
    Computation & 1.53 & 2.29 & 3.65 & 4.92 & 6.4 & 7.1 & 7.6 \\
    Apps \& Analytics & 0.52 & 0.99 & 1.69 & 3.45 & 5.29 & 6.65 & 7.75 \\
    Professional Services & 2.8 & 4.42 & 6.15 & 10.1 & 13.5 & 16 & 17.2 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{This is the caption for complicated table}
  \label{tab:1}
\end{strip}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]