# Make a table span multiple columns surrounded by text on the same page?

Tags: tables, two-column, wrap

I want to make a very wide table that must span across two columns, like this:

```
1 Test text etc etc see this table:   3 The page text wraps over
----------------------------------------------------------------
| Very                 | Wide               | Table            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
2 Because the table is so wide...     4 and around it!
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/making-a-table-span-multiple-columns) does not answer the question because the solution shunts the table onto the next page instead of integrating it with the text.

Comment: You might be interested in may answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328762/wrapping-text-in-table-latex/328791#328791).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!